# Flask File Write and Reading in Different Routes

Tags: python, flask

I have two input entries in HTML file
I read the region(input field) (CLEAR ALL FILE DATA ) and store it in a file

```
#default page of our web-app
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
     
        date = request.form["date"]
        region =request.form["region"]
        print("REGION:HOME",region)
        f = open("file.txt", "r+")
        f.truncate(0) # need '0' when using r+
        f.write(region)
        f.close()

        #dataframe =df
    return render_template("index.html")
```

THEN read the same file data in this route

```
@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    '''
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    '''
    f = open("file.txt", "r")

    reg=f.read()
    print("REGION:DOWNLOAD" ,reg)
    p = "download.csv"
    return send_file(p,as_attachment=True)
```

BUT the file reading does not have same data .Although the file written is correctly.
I also tried to store region variable as global but it does not solve my problem

Comment: From the code it is not quite clear what "download.csv" is. In your default route you write the data to "file.txt", but in the download route you send at the end the file "download.csv", even though you start with opening "file.txt". have you tried using: return send_file("file.txt", as_attachment=True)

Comment: @kayos "download.csv" is a file in directory I am sending as attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question
One thing I was missing is
"cache_timeout=0"

It solves my problem

'''

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
 return send_from_directory(p,"simple_download.csv",
as_attachment=True,cache_timeout=0)
```

'''